# what is the meaning of $(-)\otimes_R N?$

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation

I have  some confusion on this [notation](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flat+module)

It is written that

> An $R -$module   $N$ is flat  if  tensoring  with $N$ over  $R$ as  a  functor  from $R $ Mod to itself
> $(-)\otimes_R N: R Mod \to RMod$ is an exact  functor  ( sends  short  exact  sequences  to short  exact  sequences )

**My confusion** : Im not getting the  meaning of $(-)\otimes_R N?$

**My attempt** : I was  reading Atiyah book  .In Atiyah  book it is written that

> $N$ is  flat   if  $N \to M' \to  M'' \to 0$  is  any  any exact seqence  of  $A$ modules , then tensored  sequence  $ 0  \to  M' \otimes N \to M \otimes N  \to M'' \otimes N \to 0$  is  exact.

Comment: It's defining a functor i.e. it is the functor that sends $A \mapsto A \otimes_R N$. This functor being exact means exactly what Atiyah's book says i.e. tensoring with $N$ over $R$ preserves exactness

Comment: okay@OsamaGhani that  means$ A \cong (-)\otimes_R N$ ? Am i right ?

Comment: Not sure I quite understand what you mean. Basically, you have a functor $F: RMod \to RMod$ such that $F(A) = A \otimes_R N$. Now, $F$ being exact means that if $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ is exact then $0 \to F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C) \to 0$ is exact i.e. $0 \to A \otimes_R N \to B \otimes_R N \to C \otimes_R N \to 0$ is exact.

Comment: You could say $F(-) = (-) \otimes_R N$ and this may help explain the notation that you're asking about

Comment: okay @OsamaGhani. Actually ,my question is :  Is $ (-) \otimes_R N= A \otimes_R N$?

Comment: okay @OsamaGhani Got it thank You

Comment: I urge you to read a book I bought 50 years ago "Algebre Commutative" by N.Bourbaki, especially chapitre 1: Modules Plats. I believe Bourbaki has been translated into English but if you wish to become a mathematical academic you should be able to read as many languages as possible.

Comment: okay , I will  try  to read this book@P.Lawrence Thanks !